# main() arguments in java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm trying to write a code for a program that recives strings as an input. 
The program prints "Error" when the user does not  put any data, otherwise it prints the first string argument.

Is it right to refer to no data as a "null"? 
It does not work. what should I write instead?

```
public class Try {
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args[0]==null){
        System.out.println("Error- please type a string");
    }else {System.out.println(args[0]);}

    }
}
```

Comment: @Mahesh: This is not true in Java. args[0] is always the first argument, if there is at least one (else, the array length is 0)

Comment: @JB Nizet- You are correct. Just confused with `C++`. Will delete my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arguments will never be `null` if they exist in the first place -- to check that, you should use `args.length` instead:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not quite - you want `args.length==0`:

```
if (args.length==0){
    System.out.println("Error- please type a string");
}
else {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

With your current code it'll throw an exception if there isn't an argument, since the array will be of 0 length and accessing any element will thus throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 3):

you can check the value of args's attribute "length", if the value is 0, which means the user does not put any data

```
public class Try {
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error- please type a string");
    } else {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is being called from the command line.  If the user doesn't provide any arguments then `args` will be of length 0, so `args[0]` will be an index out of bounds error.  Instead of checking null you want to check the length of `args`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to test if `args.length` is 0.